# Angular/HTML Glass-pane on a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

How is it possible to make a glass-pane (e.g. with hourglass) on an HTML element E, only within E's boundaries?
By glass-pane we mean, say a semi-transparent  that has an hourglass, overlapping just the area in the E element boundaries. When the glass-pane is active anything in its background is inaccessible.
We tried using the **uibModal** lib, but it spreads all over the window, while we need to overlap only a specific element.

Thank you,

Rami

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is using the mighty z-index property and some opacity.

Let's suppose you have a lateral element with 300px of width and 100vh of height:

```
<aside style="width:300px; height:100vh; float:right; z-index:1;"> </aside>
```

Now, all you have to do is to insert a div in it with position:absolute (to not interfere with the other objects of your div) and an **higher** value of z-index:

```
<aside class="parent">
  <div class="pane"></div>
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
    width:300px; /*or your width/height settings...*/
    height:100vh; 
    float:right; /*just for the example, you can set your div wherever you want*/
    z-index:1; 
}
.pane{
    height:100vh; /*needed to fill your parent div*/
    width: 300px; 
    z-index:2; 
    position:absolute; 
    opacity: 0.6; /*pane effect*/
 }
```

This way, you'll end having a "watermark" on your div not clickable, and with a pane effect.